# MissingRuleException in Snakemake after code changes

Tags: snakemake

I have these two rules:

```
all_participants = ['01','03','04','05','06','07','08']
rule all:
    input: expand("data/interim/tables/screen/p{participant_id}.csv",participant_id=all_participants)

rule extract_screen_table:
    output: "data/interim/tables/screen/p{participant_id}.csv"
    shell: "python src/data/sql_table_to_csv.py --table screen"
```

If I execute snakemake everything works, but if I change the code and execute: `snakemake -n -R 'snakemake --list-code-changes'` I get this error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce snakemake --list-code-changes (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

The output of `snakemake --list-code-change` is:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
data/interim/tables/screen/p03.csv
```

which I reckon it shouldn't be, and I should get the python script instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use backticks for the list-code-changes: `` `snakemake --list-code-changes` ``. This is bash syntax for execute the contained command and return STDOUT as a string.

Comment: Thanks, for those using Powershell you can do `snakemake -n -R $(snakemake --lc)`. However, the output of --lc is still incorrect, I don't know if I should open a new question but the command is returning one of the input CSV files (the one described in my first question) instead of the py script I modified.

Comment: Right, I've read the docs and understood what's happening. I had to change `shell` by `run` in the rule body, then it returns a list of all the files generated with the previous version of the py script. The problem now is that is not finding the rule to produce that file. I've tried manually with `snakemake -n -R data/interim/tables/screen/p07.csv` and is returning `No rule to produce data\interim\tables\screen\p07.csv (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).`. Maybe it's a problem with the expand?